# PIVOT function in proc sql statement in SAS 9.4 not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sas

below is the code and error I get, can anyone help?

```
     proc sql;
    SELECT DateOfFill, DUEXIS AS DUEXIS, PENNSAID AS PENNSAID, RAYOS AS RAYOS,VIMOVO AS VIMOVO
     FROM (select DateOfFill, product, ftrx from PSKW.PSKWMaster) src
    pivot
    (
    sum(ftrx) for [Product] in 
    (DUEXIS, PENNSAID,RAYOS,VIMOVO)) PVT;
    quit;



ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.

5    (
6    sum(ftrx) for [Product] in
7    ([DUEXIS], [PENNSAID],[RAYOS],[VIMOVO])) PVT;
8    quit;
```

NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
NOTE: PROCEDURE SQL used (Total process time):
      real time           0.03 seconds
      cpu time            0.01 seconds

9    SELECT DateOfFill, DUEXIS AS DUEXIS, PENNSAID AS PENNSAID, RAYOS AS RAYOS,VIMOVO AS VIMOVO
     ------
     180
ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.

```
10    FROM (select DateOfFill, product, ftrx from PSKW.PSKWMaster) src
11   pivot
12   (
13   sum(ftrx) for [Product] in
14   (DUEXIS, PENNSAID,RAYOS,VIMOVO)) PVT;

15   quit;
```

Comment: there seems to be a close brace missing for the opening brace after `pivot`

Comment: Hint.  Count number of `(` then count number of `)`.  Do they match?

Comment: Change `..[VIMOVO]) PVT` --> `..[VIMOVO])) PVT`

Comment: @Utsav -- Brace = `{` or `}`, Parenthesis = `(` or `)`

Comment: If this is SAS, PROC SQL does not support PIVOT command, except in direct pass through to the server.

Comment: thanks, that must be why! I'll find a work around.

Comment: Can you use a data step? Usually when PIVOT's are required there are PROCS in SAS that accomplish the same thing with relative ease and less code :)

Comment: Yes, I can use a macro to denorm the data, which is what I did, but when using a ODBC connection to our DB I wanted to use SQL to write in the SQL command text under properties in data...but ultimately, I created an ODBC connect to my SAS dataset.

Answer (score 3):

That does not look like valid syntax for PROC SQL.  Perhaps you meant to use a passthru query into your SQL database?

```
proc sql;
  connect to odbc (.....);
  select * from connection to odbc
     (select ... pivot ... )
  ;
quit;
```